# How can I deserialize xml with 2 different types of the same xml element and property name?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

In the database, we have an xml field that contains 2 validation schemas; the old one does not have a namespace, the new one does. The reason for this is that we had to version one of the properties. Here is an example of the differences:

Version 1

```
<PropertyA>
  <PropertyA1>false</PropertyA1>
  <PropertyA2>3.23</PropertyA2>
</PropertyA>
```

Version 2

```
<ts:PropertyA xmlns:ts="http://www.example.com/v2">
  <ts:PropertyA1>false</ts:PropertyA2>
  <ts:PropertyA2>
    <ts:PropertyA2a>
        <ts:PropertyA2a1>City 1</ts:PropertyA2a1>
        <ts:PropertyA2a2>3.23</ts:PropertyA2a2>
    </ts:PropertyA2a>
    <ts:PropertyA2b>
        <ts:PropertyA2b1>City 2</ts:PropertyA2b1>
        <ts:PropertyA2b2>1.21</ts:PropertyA2b2>
    </ts:PropertyA2b>
  </ts:PropertyA2>
</ts:PropertyA>
```

Basically, we just create multiple options for PropertyA2...

So now the isue is deserialization. This object needs to be deserialized into the same data object in the app code and the problem is that the element name is the same so the serializer is obviously having trouble figuring out which object to deserialize into since sometimes the database will return Version 1 and sometimes it will return Version 2.

Here is an example of the data class being used for serialization and my current approach that isn't quite working:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyDataClass
{
    // ... other stuff

    [XmlElement(Name = "PropertyA", typeof(V1.PropertyA), Namespace = "")]
    public V1.PropertyA PropertyAV1 { get ;set; }

    [XmlElement(Name = "PropertyA", typeof(V2.PropertyA), Namespace = "http://www.example.com/v2")]
    public V2.PropertyA PropertyAV2 { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class V1.PropertyA
{
    public bool PropertyA1 { get; set; }

    public decimal PropertyA2 { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class V2.PropertyA
{
    public bool PropertyA1 { get; set; }

    public List<SomeOtherThing> PropertyA2 { get; set; }
}
```

When I go to deserialize V1, it works fine. When I go to deserialize V2, i get an error `Did not expect <ts:PropertyA xmlns:ts="http://www.example.com/v2">` so I'm thinking there's a parameter I'm missing in the deserialize method:

```
public MyDataClass Deserialize(string xml)
{
    var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof (MyDataClass));
    MyDataClass info = null;
    using (var r = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        info = (MyDataClass) s.Deserialize(r);
    }
    return info;
}
```

I believe you can set the expected namespace in the serializer, but since I don't know what the namespace is going to be until I actually inspect the xml document, I'm not sure how to proceed.

So my question is this: Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Am I on the right track? Is there a better solution that is maybe less contrived? How can I have the serializer deal with the new namespace and deserialize to the correct properties?

Comment: Are you able to change the XML so that the root node `PropertyA` is in the same namespace in both versions?

Comment: TSQL wont allow that. Each schema has to belong to a different namespace

Comment: You can write an adapter that will try deserialize with one namespace and if not success than will proceed with second namespace. Or, really, write up a utility that will go and convert all data in the DB to a new namespace

Comment: @T.S. I considered both of those things actually, but the failed deserialization is met with an exception and the last thing I want to do is have a chain of exceptions as retry logic since they are expensive. Modifying millions of database records is a last resort since the risk of failure is kinda high and roll-back would be difficult if not impossible; and I'm not sure if that would help anything sql server only allows multiple validation schemas if they are in a different namespace.

Comment: What if v2 was not implemented as a new schema? Could you add `<ts:PropertyA2>` to the existing schema?

Comment: That still goes back to modifying all of the existing xml data in the database which is dangerous. But what would that solve?

Comment: This would allow you to treat v2 as an extension of v1, instead of v1 and v2 being totally different things (because they are entirely in separate namespaces). You would end up with `<PropertyA>` having children `<PropertyA1>`, `<PropertyA2>` and `<ts:PropertyA2>`. I dont have much experience with sql schema collections, but I would assume this is an alter xml schema operation and you wouldn't need to touch the data.

Comment: I see. Yeah, i don't think that'll meet our purposes. We are not necessarily extending the data, we are replacing a property -- from a decimal to an object. We do not want the old property to be present in the new data because the data would no longer make sense if it had both.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The problem here is that you have to hardcode MyDataClass according to a single XMLSchema. If the XMLSchema alters, MyDataClass is no longer a valid target for the XMLSerializer's deserialize method, which is why you're getting the 'Did not expect ...' error message. In this case, when reading the V2 xml data stream, the deserialize method tries to fill MyDataClass#PropertyAV1 with the content of <ts:PropertyA2> and there is no way of telling it to instead fill MyDataClass#PropertyAV2. Even if there was a way to achieve this, you'd be stuck with an undefined value for MyDataClass#PropertyAV1 in the object of type MyDataClass.

So there are two solutions to the problem at hand :

a) Stick with XMLSerializer and define class MyDataClass like so

```
    public class MyDataClass 
    {    
        // only one Property here, as there's only one root element in the xml
        // and this single Property is not bound to a specific XML element
        [XmlAnyElement]    
        public PropertyA PropertyA { get ;set; }
    }
```

You then have to analyze the contents of PropertyA yourself and build some logic around it, see here for more details :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx

b) Dispense the XMLSerializer, read the XML data stream with XMLReader and do the all the parsing of the xml yourself, also add logic to create the according C# objects, depending on the the type of xml you've read.

Obviously, both solutions require more coding on the C# side, but with solution b) you'll have the chance of gaining a performance benefit, as XMLSerializer#deserialize most probably builds a DOM tree to create the C# object from, which the XMLReader doesn't do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what I was trying to do was either unachievable  or no one with the right level of xml fu saw this thread :(.

So anyway, what I ended up doing was adding an extra column to the database with the version number of the xml contract. Since everything in there was the same, I just called it V1.

I then read that info out into app code and used the version number to drive a factory. Basically, if v1, then deserialize to this, if v2, deserialize to this other thing.

And of course, to support that, I simply created a new data object that had the appropriate structure to support v2. I'm not happy with it, but it works and is flexible enough :/